# is it safe to upload multiple files to s3 synchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using Node and AWS javascript SDK. The workflow is like this:
Web app calls an API to get a few files created and downloaded to EBS,then these files are uploaded to s3. Depending on file sizes etc, it is possible that one file starts uploading while another uploading hasn't finished yet.
Is this ok to s3?Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is possible that one file starts uploading while another uploading hasn't finished yet

It is normal, but this means asynchronous upload. Synchronous loading means, that you start to upload next file after previous one was uploaded.

IMO, the best way is to run async (batch) uploading, collect responces from S3 and then send back URIs of uploaded files.

Comment: there will be too many res.send(...). I'd better use callback to upload one by one.